# Graphic in iOs device is all distorted Unity

Tags: ios, opengl-es, unity-game-engine, textures

Right now I'm developing application for iOs by Unity3D, and I have no idea what's happening with all my graphic. All textures are absolutely distorted and I've been struggling with this for a long time with no success.

I believe Unity compresses textures before convert the project to iOS, but I really can't find out how to change this setting or even knock it off. I appreciate any help from you guys. Here's the screenshot of my Texture Settings. I've setup it according to Ray Wenderlich lesson.

[image]

P.S.: I've tried to use "Point" for Filter Mode, but it had made the texture even worse.

Comment: Please add a screenshot/photo/etc of what "absolutely distorted" actually means. Are your textures power-of-two?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest disabling mitmaps to see if this solves your problem, and making sure you have the best quality settings in Edit>Player Settings>Quality

As an aside, how large is your button image? You're overriding the max size to be 2048 for what seems to be a button. That sounds a little excessive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah, you're right, I've crossed the line a little with Max Size. But anyway, if I setup smaller size it makes no difference at all ((

Answer (score 0):

By "distorted" you mean "blurred"? Try to uncheck "Generate Mip Maps".

Comment: Thank you for your response. Whenever I uncheck Generate Mip Maps texture becomes worse. But it was in Unity environment, is there any chance that in iOs it will have different look?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could show us how your textures look outside the unity, in unity and in iOS build.